# Combining preprocessor macros and variables

Tags: c++, macros

In my C++ code I have to execute certain code under two conditions: because of a preprocessor macro OR a boolean variable check. For example:

```
bool done=false;
#ifdef _DEBUG
executeDebugCode();
done=true;
#endif

if (inputParam && !done)
    executeDebugCode();
```

Is there a way to write the above code in a more elegant way, without repeating the `executeDebugCode()` function call two times?

EDIT:
the `executeDebugCode()` function should be executed once, and if one of the two condition is met. For example a function that should be executed in DEBUG mode only, that could be set by preprocessor macro or command line parameter.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Should the fuction be called if *either* condition is met or only if *both* are met? And if both are met, should it be called once or twice?

Comment: @Angew Presumably the shortened "more elegant" way should have the same behavior as the code above.

Comment: Edited to be more clear. Sorry, something usually pops in mind later thank to answers and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to execute this code only once, if at least one of these conditions is true:

```
    if ( inputParam
#ifdef DEBUG
        || true
#endif
       )
{
    executeDebugCode();
}
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Differently from other answers (all good) no additional variable is declared or defined.

Answer (score 1):

The form I see most for this, and which tends to work well, is do make the exact check performed depend on `_DEBUG`, so you'd get:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define SHOULD_EXECUTE_DEBUG_CODE() 1
#else
#define SHOULD_EXECUTE_DEBUG_CODE() inputParam
#endif

if (SHOULD_EXECUTE_DEBUG_CODE())
  executeDebugCode();
```

Note that if `inputParam` is a local variable (as Sambuca points out in the comments), this macro `SHOULD_EXECUTE_DEBUG_CODE` cannot be used in other functions, and for maintainability, it may be worth adding `#undef SHOULD_EXECUTE_DEBUG_CODE` at the end of the function to prevent accidental misuse.

Comment: I didn't know I could define a macro inside a function...good to know

Comment: What I personally don't like is that the name of a (local) variable is inserted using a macro. Considering if you want to use this "preprocessor switch" at another point in your codebase.

Comment: @Sambuca If `inputParam` is a local variable (and re-reading now, it looks as if it is), then I agree, and I would make sure to `#undef` it at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
bool debugEnabled = inputParam;
#ifdef _DEBUG
debugEnabled = true;
#endif

if (debugEnabled)
    executeDebugCode()
```

ie. use one flag to control the code behavior, but allow that flag to be set in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

This will not generate any overhead in runtime if DEBUG is not enabled.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define MY_DEBUG true
#else
#define MY_DEBUG false
#endif

if ( inputParam || MY_DEBUG )
        executeDebugCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be something like this

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define SHOULD_EXECUTE 1
#else
#define SHOULD_EXECUTE 0
#endif

if (SHOULD_EXECUTE || inputParam) {
  executeDebugCode();
}
```

This way your if-statement shows right away that you're checking on a preprocessor define and another (boolean) condition.